# How many times will this loop execute?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, iteration

I'm taking an algorithms course, and I'm having a tough time figuring out how many times the following loop will execute.  I think the answer is log(n) (because of the mid=i/2), but I'm having a hard time convincing myself.  Any help or tips on figuring out how many times this loop will iterate would be great.  Thanks!

```
def loop(arr):

    i = len(arr) - 1
    mid = i/2

    while i > 0:
         i = mid - 1
         mid = (i)/2
```

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially performing a binary search, without the search part.  You have a space and you keep dividing it in half, until you are done.

That is O(log(n)).

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

On a side note, it can be instructive to run your algorithm for a variety of inputs for i, and graph the runtime as a function of i.  You may want to insert a constant delay for each iteration (e.g. sleep(50) or so) because the loop will otherwise run very fast.